# Как добавить дополнительную информацию по установленной программе?

Tags: c#, installshield

Всем привет. Есть разработанное приложение. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где нужно и что нужно сделать, чтобы после установки ПО было написано так, как в примере ниже (ссылка справки и ссылка на службу поддержки):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую в качестве установщика InstallShield